# how to pass query string and get object result in Express.js on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, query-string

I create my api in nodeJs and express and I want to get an object by passing string parameter but i can't get this object.

This is my app

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const produits = [
      {
         "codeProduit":"78",
         "nomCat":"nomCat11",
         "typeCat":"typeCat11"
      },
      {
         "codeProduit":"82",
         "nomCat":"nomCat21",
         "typeCat":"typeCat21"
      },
      {
         "codeProduit":"69",
         "nomCat":"nomCat31",
         "typeCat":"typeCat31"
      }
 ]


//http://localhost:3000/produits?codeProduit=78
app.get('/produits', (req, res) => {
    if(req.query.codeProduit != undefined && req.query.codeProduit != '') {
        res.json(produits[(req.query.codeProduit)])
    }  else {
        res.json(produits)
    }
     
 })
 
 app.get('/produits', (req, res) => {
      res.json(produits)
  })

  app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log('Started on port 3000')
  })
```

I want to get this object

```
{
 "codeProduit":"78",
 "nomCat":"nomCat11",
 "typeCat":"typeCat11"
}
```

when i call this url : http://localhost:3000/produits?codeProduit=78

How can i do it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing `produits[78]` which is undefined, so you need to use `find` to get the expected produit

```
app.get('/produits', (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.codeProduit != undefined && req.query.codeProduit != '') {
    const result = produits.find(p => p.codeProduit === req.query.codeProduit);
    result ? res.json(200).json(result) : res.status(404).json();
  } else {
    res.json(produits);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @tam.teixeira, thanks for your solution, it works well. Now how to manage the error case in an else if the product code does not exist or is incorrect. Example http://localhost:3000/produits?codeProduit=76 or http://localhost:3000/produits?codeProduit=7

Comment: @lulu3131 i've edited the answer to handle that, it returns `404` HTTP status code. Since i answered your question please mark it as answered.